# Como remover campo a campo de uma String começando pela esquerda e delimitado por um tamanho desejado pelo usuário

Tags: java, string

```
package teste;

public class RemoverStringAEsquerda {
    
    public static String removerCampoAEsquerda(String value, int tamanhoMaximoString) {
        int i = 0;
        while (value.length() >= tamanhoMaximoString){
            value = value.substring(i);
            i++;
        }
        
        return value;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String campo = "0010004500000000023456841466512";
        campo = removerCampoAEsquerda(campo, 14);
        System.out.println(campo);
    
    }

}
```

Resultado esperado: `23456841466512`

Ou caso o tamanho desejado da String seja 5: `removerCampoAEsquerda(campo, 5)` - o resultado esperado é `66512`

Answer (score 0):

> Sua solução não é a ideal, mas primeiro vamos corrigir o seu código, e depois veremos uma solução mais simples.

---

O problema é que você incrementa o `i`. Ou seja, na primeira iteração, você pega `substring(0)` (que não é lá muito "esperto", já que assim você pega toda a string).

Depois, na segunda iteração, `i` vale 1, então `substring(1)` pega do segundo caractere em diante. Ou seja, o primeiro caractere foi eliminado.

Na terceira iteração, `i` vale 2, então `substring(2)` pega do terceiro caractere em diante. Mas lembre-se que o primeiro caractere da string original já foi eliminado, ou seja, o terceiro caractere aqui equivale ao quarto caractere da string original.

Na quarta iteração, `i` vale 3 então `substring(3)` pega do quarto caractere em diante. Mas já vimos que o passo anterior eliminou os primeiros 4 caracteres, então o quarto caractere aqui equivale ao oitavo caractere da string original.

E assim por diante... A cada iteração, você está eliminando vários caracteres a mais.

Se a ideia era fazer um *loop*, então elimine sempre o primeiro caractere:

```
public static String removerCampoAEsquerda(String value, int tamanhoMaximoString) {
    while (value.length() > tamanhoMaximoString) { // se o tamanho for menor ou igual ao máximo, nem entra no while
        value = value.substring(1); // sempre pegue do segundo caractere em diante
    }
    return value;
}
```

---

Mas como eu já disse no início, essa solução está longe de ser a melhor. Não tem porque ficar criando várias strings à toa (cada chamada de `substring` cria uma nova string). Na verdade o que você quer é pegar os últimos caracteres da string, então só precisa chamar `substring` uma única vez:

```
public static String ultimosCaracteres(String value, int tamanhoMaximo) {
    if (value.length() <= tamanhoMaximo) { // se o tamanho for menor ou igual ao máximo, não precisa modificar a string
        return value;
    }
    // pega os últimos caracteres da string
    return value.substring(value.length() - tamanhoMaximo);
}
```

Testando:

```
String campo = "0010004500000000023456841466512";
System.out.println(ultimosCaracteres(campo, 14)); // 23456841466512
System.out.println(ultimosCaracteres(campo, 5));  // 66512
```

Comment: Agora entendi como deve proceder e tbm na onde estava pecando no codigo, vlw mesmo hkotsudo

Comment: @Etgames13 Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.